# how access emebed objects in MapReduce MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have the following document in mongo:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("501535acd729190bd62e3a58"),
        "o_orderkey" : NumberLong(1),
        "o_custkey" : {
                "$ref" : "customer",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5012e490cabc8baea9a541dd")
        },
        "o_orderstatus" : "O",
        "o_totalprice" : 173665.47,
        "o_orderdate" : ISODate("1996-01-02T02:00:00Z"),
        "o_orderpriority" : "5-LOW",
        "o_clerk" : "Clerk#000000951",
        "o_shippriority" : 0,
        "o_comment" : "blithely final dolphins solve-- blithely blithe packages nag blith",
        "o_lineitem" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("501535abd729190bd62e38c7"),
                        "orderKey" : NumberLong(1),
                        "l_partkey" : {
                                "$ref" : "part",
                                "$id" : ObjectId("500f3a03d7292535356b839c")
                        },
                        "l_supplierkey" : {
                                "$ref" : "supplier",
                                "$id" : ObjectId("4ffed5dd125ee93ca6f3b294")
                        },
                        "l_linenumber" : 1,
                        "l_quantity" : 17,
                        "l_extendedprice" : 21168.23,
                        "l_discount" : 0.04,
                        "l_tax" : 0.02,
                        "l_returnflag" : "N"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("501535abd729190bd62e38c8"),
                        "orderKey" : NumberLong(1),
                        "l_partkey" : {
                                "$ref" : "part",
                                "$id" : ObjectId("500f398ed7292535356a2c54")
                        },
                        "l_supplierkey" : {
                                "$ref" : "supplier",
                                "$id" : ObjectId("4ffed5dd125ee93ca6f3b109")
                        },
                        "l_linenumber" : 2,
                        "l_quantity" : 36,
                        "l_extendedprice" : 45983.16,
                        "l_discount" : 0.09,
                        "l_tax" : 0.06,
                        "l_returnflag" : "N"
                }
        ]
}
```

And i need to sum "l_quantity" when "o_shippriority"=0 and "l_linenumber"=1
I've tried this:

```
db.runCommand({ 
    mapreduce: "orders", 
    query: {
        o_shippriority: 0,
        "l_lineitem.l_linenumber": 1
    },
    map : function Map() {
        emit("sum",{this.o_lineitem}); 
    },
    reduce : function Reduce(key, values) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            var lineitem = values[i];
            for (var j=0; j<lineitem.length; j++) {
                sum += lineitem.l_quantity;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    },  
    out: 'query'
});
```

Doesn't work i received "SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):8"
whats wrong?

Comment: that should be o_lineitem.l_linenumber according to your schema.  Your emit is not correct - you have to output a number, so no {} around it. But what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having with the syntax error is because of the line:

```
emit("sum",{this.o_lineitem});
```

Which should either be a proper document: `emit("sum", {line:this.o_lineitem})` or not be a document at all: `emit("sum", this.o_lineitem")` depending on what you are going to do in your reduce.

The other issue you will have to begin with is that the `query` is not going to return anything, you will need `"o_lineitem.l_linenumber": 1` instead of `"l_lineitem.l_linenumber": 1` since your document doesn't have a `l_lineitem`.

You are going to have further problems with this query however, because when you find `o_lineitem.l_linenumber:1` you will return the whole document - including the `l_linenumber`'s that are not 1.  You are going to need to iterate through the array you are emitting and sum only when the `l_linenumber` = 1.